# (React) Trouble Centering with Display flex

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, center

I'm having some trouble centering a div. I know, I know, cliche. I've tried using AlignItems and display flex and both don't work. I can do left: 20px and that moves it but I want it to be responsive based on the phone they are using.

I am using React and I'm making a frost effect but it's sticking to the left side as shown
[image: here]

Here is the code I am using:

```
function BottomText() {
  const style = {
    h3: {
      textAlign: "center",
      position: "relative",
      
    },
    p: {
      textAlign: "center",
      position: "relative",
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          position: "relative",
        }}
      >
        Who We Are
      </h3>
      <p
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          position: "relative",
          paddingBottom: "20px",
          borderBottom: ".5px solid white",
        }}
      >
        Kingdom Man Ministry is a Men’s ministry birthed out of our Senior
        Pastor, Mike Kai’s heart to lead men into an authentic Christ-centered
        life. We believe that through the lessons and principles found in Jesus’
        life we can disciple each other to reject passivity, accept
        responsibility, lead courageously and invest eternally.
      </p>

      <h3 style={style.h3}>Our Mission</h3>

      <p style={style.p}>
        The mission of Kingdom Man Ministry is to inspire men to live with
        generational vision; we do that in three steps. Reach Men, Foster
        Discipleship, and Live like Jesus.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}


const style = {
  frost: {
    position: "relative",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
    boxShadow: "inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)",
    backdropFilter: "blur(5px)",
    backgroundColor:"#6c757d4d",
    width: "90%",
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: "10px 10px",
    top: "100px",
    borderRadius: "25px",
  },
};

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TopText />
      <div classname="container" style={style.frost}>
        <BottomText />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Here is a codepen that i made to recreate the problem:
[Recreated CodePen](https://codepen.io/shaneeyb/pen/xxYxypG?editors=1100)

It might be an issue with the child div or something but I am not sure. I feel like it's an easy fix but I've been on this problem for a while.
Thanks for any comments and Happy Sunday! : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a parent element, a container, that has `display:flex` and `justify-content:center`

On your codepen; try this for example;

```
<div class="parent" style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
  <div class="bg">...</div>
</div>
```

For more info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Wow this totally works! I always find the parent and child stuff to be a little tricky but thanks for helping me figure it out! Youre the best Emre!!! Thanks so much!! : )